# Trouble creating Debian live USB

Tags: debian, boot, live-usb

I'm at a loss here; I've followed the instructions for creating a bootable Debian USB, trying a number of times, and it just doesn't seem to work.

For reference, here are the commands I'm using:

With device unmounted:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -n 'DEBIAN8_8' -I /dev/sdc1
sudo cp /home/user/Downloads/debian-live-8.8.0-amd64-standard.iso /dev/sdc1
```

The files are successfully written to the drive as far as I can tell, but I've tried booting on two different computers with no result. I'm trying a different pendrive, but I don't think there was anything wrong with the drive I was using. Is there anything I'm missing?

NOTE: I've tried the process with `sudo cp /home/jules/Downloads/debian-live-8.8.0-amd64-standard.iso /dev/sdc1` as well, to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run `cp` command as follows (to the device `sdc` , not to the partition `sdc1`):

```
sudo cp /home/user/Downloads/debian-live-8.8.0-amd64-standard.iso /dev/sdc
```

followed by `sync` command.

[debian :How do I write a CD/DVD/BD image to a USB flash drive?](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb)

```
cp <file> <device>
```